# Simple Segmentation Fault, I can't seem to find the issue

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

There's probably an easy solution to this but as a noob I can't seem to find the issue. When I first run the program everything is fine but after `scan("%f",hrs)` I get "segmentation faul (core dumped)". Any help would be appreciated, thanks. If you would like too see the full code [you can find it here.](http://pastebin.com/Y1f0e2VL/%22find%20it%20here%22)

Here's the warning I was getting: **format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double**’

```
float grossModule(float *hours, float payrate, float *overtimeHours);
void CalculateTaxes(float *gross, float *defr, float *fedtax, float *statetax, float *ssitax);
float calcFedtax(float gross, float defr);
float calcStatetax(float fedtax);
float calcSSItax(float gross, float defr);
float netModule(float *gross, float *ft, float *st, float *ssit);

int main(void)
{
    float dfr,ft,st,ssit,gross,hrs,pay,net,ovrtHrs;
    int counter = 0;
    float netTotal, payTotal, hoursTotal, overtimeTotal, grossTotal, fedTotal, stateTotal, ssiTotal, dfrTotal;
    float grossAvg, netAvg, payAvg, hoursAvg, overtimeAvg, fedAvg, stateAvg, ssiAvg, dfrAvg;
    char fName[11], lName[21], ask[4];
    FILE * myreport;
    myreport = fopen("reports.txt","wt");

fprintf(myreport, header1);
fprintf(myreport, header2);
fprintf(myreport, header3);

netTotal = payTotal = hoursTotal = overtimeTotal = grossTotal = fedTotal = stateTotal = ssiTotal = dfrTotal = 0;
dfr = ft = st = ssit = gross = hrs = pay = net = ovrtHrs = 0;

do
{
    counter++;
    printf("Please enter your FIRST name: ");
    scanf("%s",fName);
    printf("Please enter your LAST name: ");
    scanf("%s",lName);
    printf("Enter your payrate: \n");
    scanf("%f",pay);
    printf("Please enter your total hours: ");
    scanf("%f",hrs);
    printf("Please enter the amount of deferred earnings: ");
    scanf("%f",dfr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 scanf("%f",pay);
 printf("Please enter your total hours: ");
 scanf("%f",hrs);
 printf("Please enter the amount of deferred earnings: ");
 scanf("%f",dfr);Change
```

to

```
 scanf("%f", &pay);
 printf("Please enter your total hours: ");
 scanf("%f", &hrs);
 printf("Please enter the amount of deferred earnings: ");
 scanf("%f", &dfr);
```

`scanf` needs the address of the variable and not it's content.

BTW you compiler should issue warnings for this.

Comment: I think it did but being the noob that I am I din't quite understand the warning. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan Why did you not post any warnings with your code?

Comment: @MartinJames Sorry, will do next time. I'm still getting used to how things work around here. I'll edit my post and add the warnings.